# How to go about calculating first match version of birthday problem

Tags: probability

So the problem is of: People enter room one by one. The first one to enter the room and share birthday with someone already inside the room will win the prize. What position (what i-th person to enter the room) to choose to have the best chance to win?

I went about it by assuming that the best possition is the one where probabilty p=p(i)-p(i-1) is the largest so going with the ...

$p(i)= 1 - \frac{1}{365^{i}}*\frac{365!}{(365-i)!}$

it would be

$p = \frac{1}{365^{i-1}}*\frac{365!}{(364-i)!} - \frac{1}{365^{i}}*\frac{365!}{(365-i)!}$

But this ends up with numbers larger then 1 and decreasing with growing i. It is possible i made error while evaluating. In both cases i would like to ask for help as to how to properly calculate this.

Comment: Hint: Suppose the first match occurs when the $X$th person enters the room, so $P(X>n)$ is the probability that there is no match with $n$ people in the room.  Then maybe you can use $P(X=n) = P(X>n)-P(X>n+1)$ to find $P(X=n)$.

Comment: @awkward so that would be P(X=i) = (1/365^(i-2))*(365!/(365-(i-2))!) - (1/365^(i-1))*(365!/(365-(i-1))!) ? Did i get it right?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but I made a mistake in my previous comment.  I should have written $P(X=n) = P(X>n-1) - P(X>n)$.

Comment: Could you give me adition hints? I can't figure it out.

Comment: You almost have it in your previous comment.  Just apply $P(X=i) = P(X>i-1)-P(X>i)$.  If you're having trouble with $P(X>i)$, that is just the probability that there is no match with $i$ people in the room (which I think you already have figured out).

Comment: So probability that right now there will be match minus probability that in the last round there was no match, do i understand correctly?